# Qt4 installed but CTK's CMake cannot find it

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have installed Qt4.8 but when I try to build [CTK](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Main_Page), I get the error in `message()` below

This is an excerpt from its `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CTK_QT_VERSION "4" CACHE STRING "Expected Qt version")
mark_as_advanced(CTK_QT_VERSION)
set_property(CACHE CTK_QT_VERSION PROPERTY STRINGS 4 5)

if(NOT (CTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL "4" OR CTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL "5"))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Expected value for CTK_QT_VERSION is either '4' or '5'")
endif()
```

I don't clearly understand how `CTK_QT_VERSION` is determined here. Why is it thinking my Qt version is not 4?

Comment: ***I don't clearly understand how CTK_QT_VERSION is determined here.*** It's not determined automatically. You are supposed to set it yourself. Did you set the value of `CTK_QT_VERSION` in cmake-gui? Since it is marked as advanced you need to enable viewing advanced variables in cmake-gui. There is a checkbox on the toolbar for that.